# How do you change the download directory for youtube-dl

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl for a Discord Music Bot, everything works perfectly until I use the 'play' command. An error occurs **"Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'National Anthem of USSR-U06jlgpMtQs.webm.part'"** from what I have read (and what the error says) it is because youtube-dl doesn't have permission to download filed to a certain folder. So I'd imagine that an easy solution is to just change the download directory. I can't find anything on how to do it for python, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Unrelated, but love the song name,

Answer (score 1):

Found on [github's documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md) for it.

---

Locate youtube-dl's config file from:

> 1. Linux/macOS:
>
>    - System-wide config : `/etc/youtube-dl.conf`
>    - User-wide config : `~/.config/youtube-dl.conf`
> 2. Windows:
>
>    - `C:\Users\<username>\youtube-dl.conf`
>    - `%APPDATA%\youtube-dl\config.txt`

If non-existent, you can create it yourself.

**Example file contents:**

```
-o A:/path/to/file/%(title)s.%(ext)s
```

---

**References:**

- [Flag to specify a file path.](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-put-downloads-into-a-specific-folder)
- [Setting up config file.](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time to figure out on Windows 10 and it might help someone in the future.

I've downloaded youtube-dl.exe from the latest build and downloaded by executing, youtube-dl.exe URL, from my home directory. The program says downloaded completed but *** it was not there so I issued the command again, and it says there already exist file @#$@%!@#%$. Well, I found out -o option to change the name of the downloaded file and it finally helped me to search for the file and the following location was the default directory.

Go to C:\Users[YOUR USER NAME GOES HERE]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore